# How do I create a pop up window using the AppDrag CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, developer-tools

I want a **new modal** to open up upon the clicking of a link.  Can I achieve that using the page builder, and not the code editor in **developer mode**?

Answer (score 2):

In PageBuilder double click on the button where you want to set your modal popup trigger then click on "Link", there set your target page or external url then set the "open mode" to "Modal"

You can also configure there the size of the modal and if you want to set a Title